# Running JVM 6 compiled code on JVM 5 or lower

Tags: java

What is the effect of executing a class compiled to byte code on a JVM Version 6 and execution the same on a lower version JVM (say 1.4)?

Comment: JVM doesn't compile code, but if you need using target as java6 and trying to run w/ jdk1.4, you can get verification errors and/or NoClassDefFounfError, etc. Java is backward compatible only.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure what you're asking really, but if you compile a Java source file targeting Java 6, it will not execute on an older JVM (say, 1.4).

```
: ~/tmp > javac -version
javac 1.6.0_22
: ~/tmp > javac Test.java 
: ~/tmp > java Test
Hello World
: ~/tmp > module add jdk/1.4.2    # switching to Java 1.4.2
: ~/tmp > java Test
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError:
                Test (Unsupported major.minor version 50.0)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:539)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:123)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:251)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:55)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:194)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:187)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:289)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:274)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:235)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(ClassLoader.java:302)
: ~/tmp >
```

---

As pointed out by @The-MeLLeR however, you can still use the 1.6 compiler to compile to 1.4 compatible code, by using the `-target` option. However **keep in mind that this only works if you're not using any 1.5/1.6 specific features or API classes**.

If you for instance try to compile a for-each loop, with `-target 1.4` you'll get something similar to the following message:

```
Test.java:3: ';' expected
        for (int i : new int[] { 1, 2, 3 })
                   ^
```

Comment: Unless compiled with --target ;)

Comment: You can still compile for each loops with --target 1.4, it is --source 1.4 which will provoke the error above.

Comment: The above message was produced with `-target` on my machine.

Comment: @jmg: you cannot use -target 1.4 without (explicitly or implicitly) using -source 1.4

Comment: @Michael Hmm, I wasn't aware of that. But you can still use Retroweaver to achieve the same, as pointed out by Esko Luontola.

Answer (score 1):

Unless compiled with the -target command line option, it will not run on a older JVM.

When compiled with the -target option, the compiled classes should run 100% equal on the older (but not older then [target]) jvm.

Comment: However, the compiled program can still fail at runtime if you use parts of the standard API that are missing in the older JRE.

Answer (score 1):

If you try to use classes which have been compiled for a newer JVM than what the current JVM supports, the JVM will throw an `UnsupportedClassVersionError` when it tries to load the class. Newer class formats may have features which are not support by the older JVMs, so this is necessary.

It is possible to use javac's `-target` option to make a newer JDK produce classes using and older class format. But you will still need to be careful to not use classes or methods which exist only on the newer JRE - otherwise the JVM will throw some error on class loading. Using the same JDK version as is the target version is the safest bet.

P.S. IntelliJ IDEA has an inspection to warn if you use too new methods/classes. There is also a tool called [Retroweaver](http://retroweaver.sourceforge.net/) to run Java 5 code on Java 1.4.